# how to close FXCM FIX position

Tags: fix-protocol

i want to close a position following the instruction of FXCM official FIX guide. but failed. anyone will help me to check what's wrong here？ thanks!

```
QuickFix44.NewOrderSingle order = new QuickFix44.NewOrderSingle();
                order.setField(new QuickFix.ClOrdID("123456"));
                order.setField(account);
                order.setField(symbol);
                order.setField(new QuickFix.Side(QuickFix.Side.BUY));
                order.setField(new QuickFix.TransactTime());
                order.setField(new QuickFix.OrderQty(10000));
                order.setField(new QuickFix.OrdType(QuickFix.OrdType.MARKET));
                order.setField(9041, FXCM_Pos_ID);
                app.send(message, app.sessionID);
```

Comment: account,symbol and FXCM_Pos_ID are predefined and verified without any fault.

Comment: You failed, but with which error message?

Comment: it responses with no error hint but a message of "An order for 10,000 Buy on EUR/USD placed on 00796228 with ID NONE updated as R"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be with a duplicate ClOrdID. According to the specs, it should be unique but in your case it's the same every time.

Also, did you make sure that the position you are trying to close is the sell position?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."